# Displaying buffer in new layer using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geometry, polygon-creation

I'm trying to create a new layer, in which the buffers are displayed. I tried this code, but it does not work. Where is the error?

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
buff_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326","buffer", "memory")
bufferDist = 10

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = feat.geometry()
  buff = geom.buffer(bufferDist,5)
  feat.setGeometry(buff)
  buff_layer.addFeature(feat)   

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayers([buff_layer])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Firstly, for every feature, you have to create a new [`QgsFeature`](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsFeature.html) and set its geometry and then add it to the layer.

**Solution 1: [Edit](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorLayer.html#a1cb9fe1007c931a0e78195607ace518e) Session**

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
buff_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "buffer", "memory")
bufferDist = 10

# start edit session
buff_layer.startEditing()
for feat in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = feat.geometry()
  buff = geom.buffer(bufferDist, 5)

  # create a new empty feature
  f = QgsFeature()
  f.setGeometry(buff)
  buff_layer.addFeature(f)

# commit changes to the layer
buff_layer.commitChanges()

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buff_layer)
```

**Solution 2: Using [Data Provider](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgsVectorDataProvider.html)**

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()
buff_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:4326", "buffer", "memory")
bufferDist = 10

for feat in layer.getFeatures():
  geom = feat.geometry()
  buff = geom.buffer(bufferDist, 5)

  # create a new empty feature
  f = QgsFeature()
  f.setGeometry(buff)

  ### 
  buff_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
  ###

QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buff_layer)
```

Comment: Solution 2 is more clear.