# TypeError when adding QgsGeometry object to canvas using PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3, geometry, typeerror, qgsmapcanvas

How do we add a `QgsGeometry` in memory object using `QgsProject.addMapLayer()` or other PyQGIS code?

ERROR

> TypeError: QgsProject.addMapLayer(): argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'QgsGeometry' buffer <QgsGeometry: Polygon ((336097.91999999998370185
> 8173802.9299999997019767

CODE Snippet

```py
line_layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('b5_Dissolved_Roads_clip')[0]
chainage_layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('a3_Roads_10m_Chainage')[0] #Change name to match your chainage layer

fids = []
feats = [f for f in line_layer.getFeatures()]
start_end=-1 #0 for start, -1 for end
field_to_update='End_Chainage'
print(datetime.datetime.now())
print (feats)

for feat in feats:
    name = feat['Location']
    print (name)
    c_sel = [p for p in chainage_layer.getFeatures() if p['Location'] == name]
    print (c_sel)
    geom = feat.geometry().asPolyline()
    end_point = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(geom[start_end])
    buffer = end_point.buffer(20, 4) #Xm buffer with 4 segments
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer)
```

Running QGIS 3.26.3-Buenos Aires

Comment: Have you tried the solutions in [Display buffer in a new layer - PyQGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351612/63384)?

Comment: It already is a vector layer right? so isn't it the same as buff_layer in that link?

Comment: The original data is a vector layer, but the output of the buffer is a type of geometry as shown in the error message. Therefore, you need to create a new empty feature layer, add the buffer geometry to the newly created feature layer, then use the data provider to append all the features as a list, and finally, add it as a layer to the map canvas. `Solution 2: Using Data Provider` is easy to follow.

Comment: I tried `buffer_lyr=QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:28355","buffer", "memory")
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_lyr)` and it added but no data in the table/no object visible even though the points to build the buffer are there as per the example in my question.

Comment: Is it possible to share a sample from your data to try to help solve your problem using your code?

Comment: I worked it out...so you have to include most of the answer 2. `buffer = end_point.buffer(20, 4) #Xm buffer with 4 segments
    buffer_lyr=QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:28355","buffer", "memory")
    f = QgsFeature()
    f.setGeometry(buffer)
    buffer_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_lyr)` Seems excessive but works. I thought it would be simpler as the geometry object already exists.

Comment: It is better to add the comment as answer to help others facing the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to avoid keeping the question without an answer, as commented by @[GeorgeC](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/2891/georgec), most of the answer of solution 2 in [Display buffer in a new layer - PyQGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351612/63384) solve the problem. Specifically, adding the following code will load the buffer layer correctly:

```
buffer_lyr=QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:28355","buffer", "memory")     
f = QgsFeature()     
f.setGeometry(buffer)     
buffer_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])     
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_lyr)
```

The full code will be like this:

```py
line_layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('b5_Dissolved_Roads_clip')[0]
chainage_layer = QgsProject().instance().mapLayersByName('a3_Roads_10m_Chainage')[0] #Change name to match your chainage layer

fids = []
feats = [f for f in line_layer.getFeatures()]
start_end=-1 #0 for start, -1 for end
field_to_update='End_Chainage'
print(datetime.datetime.now())
print (feats)

for feat in feats:
    name = feat['Location']
    print (name)
    c_sel = [p for p in chainage_layer.getFeatures() if p['Location'] == name]
    print (c_sel)
    geom = feat.geometry().asPolyline()
    end_point = QgsGeometry.fromPointXY(geom[start_end])
    buffer = end_point.buffer(20, 4) #Xm buffer with 4 segments
    buffer_lyr=QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:28355","buffer", "memory")     
    f = QgsFeature()     
    f.setGeometry(buffer)     
    buffer_lyr.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])     
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_lyr)
```