# PyQGIS layer action: Add buffer from clicked-on feature as temporary layer using materialize

Tags: pyqgis, buffer, vector-layer, actions

In the workshop material ["QGIS Automation using Actions"](https://courses.spatialthoughts.com/qgis-actions.html#introduction), the first example "1.1 Extract a Feature from a Layer" demonstrates how one can extract any country polygon by clicking on it.
I would like to alter the code in that way, that a buffer of 200 km around the country I have clicked on is created and added to the map as temporary layer.

So, I reprojected the [World map layer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/407616/183146) (Admin0 - Country boundaries dataset from Natural Earth) to EPSG 3857 and adapted the example Code

```
from qgis.utils import iface

feature_name = '[%NAME%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'

layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)
new_layer = layer.materialize(
    QgsFeatureRequest().setFilterFids([feature_id]))
new_layer.setName(feature_name)
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(new_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
```

for my use case as follows (considering [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/351612/183146)):

```
from qgis.utils import iface
    
feature_name = '[%NAME%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
   
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

buffer_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3857", "buffer_200km", "memory")
buffer_distance = 200000
for feature in layer.getFeatures(layer_id):
    geom = feature.geometry()
    country_buffer = geom.buffer(buffer_distance, 5)

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(country_buffer)
buffer_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
   
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
```

When applying the action, I got the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 11, in  TypeError:
> QgsVectorLayer.getFeatures(): arguments did not match any overloaded
> call:   overload 1: argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'   overload 2:
> argument 1 has unexpected type 'int'   overload 3: argument 1 has
> unexpected type 'int'   overload 4: argument 1 has unexpected type
> 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find a working solution without the materialize method:

```
from qgis.utils import iface
        
feature_name = '[%NAME%]'
feature_id = [%$id%]
layer_id = '[%@layer_id%]'
   
layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayer(layer_id)

buffer_layer = QgsVectorLayer("Polygon?crs=epsg:3857&field=fid:integer", f'{feature_name} buffer_200km', "memory")
buffer_distance = 200000
for feature in layer.getFeatures([feature_id]): # added squared brackets
    geom = feature.geometry()
    country_buffer = geom.buffer(buffer_distance, 5)

f = QgsFeature()
f.setGeometry(country_buffer)
buffer_layer.dataProvider().addFeatures([f])
   
QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(buffer_layer)
iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
```

Exemplary result in map:
[image: result of custom action adding buffer layer]